# Factoring polynomials over finite fields

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm having some trouble understand how to test for irreducibilty of polynomials over finite fields. For example, in my text book I see $5x^4-2x^3 +9x -1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}$. They then go to say that if we consider said polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}_2$ we get $x^4+x+1$ which has no roots in $\mathbb{Z}_2$. How did they get $x^4+x+1$

$\textbf{My Attempt}$: 
$$(5x^4-2x^3+9x-1) \bmod 2 = (x^4 + 4x^4 -2x^3+x+8x-1) \bmod 2 $$
$$\qquad \quad\quad\quad=(x^4+0-0+x+0-1) \bmod 2$$

Where did the difference in sign come from? Also, when using this method to test for irreducibility, is it wise to use $\bmod 2$, since it has the easiest search space?

Comment: $-1\equiv 1\mod 2$

Comment: You use mod 2 because we are working with polynomials in $\mathbb Z_2$

Comment: As a sidenote: "Has no roots" is not the same as "is irreducible"

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I'm not quite what the difference is? Unles you're referring to "has no roots in a certain field"?

Comment: @user119264 e.g. $x^4+4$ has no roots in $\mathbb Q$ but $x^4+4=(x^4+4x^2+4)-4x^2=(x^2+2)^2-(2x)^2=(x^2+2x+2)(x^2-2x+2)$

Comment: So this polynomial has no roots but can factor into two quadratics. For polynomials of degree $\geq 4$ no roots does not imply irreducible. However for degree $\leq 3$, if a polynomial reduces then one of the factors must be linear, which gives a root, so in this case polynomials are irreducible if and only if they have a root.

Answer (score 1):

Your polynomial is equivalent:

$$
x^4+x-1 \equiv x^4+x+1 \pmod 2
$$

Comment: That should be $$x^4 +x-1\equiv x^4 + x + 1 \pmod 2$$

Comment: @JordanGlen correct. I'll fix it.